# Rails store DB object with infinite-like value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Political viewpoints aside :), say I have the following:

```
class Person    
  belongs_to :country
  attr_accessible :income
end

class Country
  has_many :people
  has_one  :tax_structure
end

class TaxStructure
  belongs_to :country
  has_many   :tax_brackets
end

class TaxBracket
  belongs_to :tax_structure
end
```

Say tax brackets are set up like so:

```
# bracket_1:
lower_bound: 0
upper_bound: 19_999
rate:        20%

# bracket_2:
lower_bound: 20_000
upper_bound: 49_999
rate:        25%

# bracket_3:
lower_bound: 50_000
upper_bound: INFINITE
rate:        30%
```

I need to lookup the person's tax bracket based on their income and the country they're from.

1) Is there a way to save, or mimic an Infinite value for the upper bound in bracket 3 that makes SQL querying super easy? I'd say make it a super large number, but that feels error prone.

2) Best way (I know subjective), to validate that the brackets don't overlap and **at least one bracket includes an infinite-like value.**

Comment: Can you just use NULL to represent that there is no upper bound?

Comment: @adanot - I could, but what does the query become then? TaxBracket.where("lower_bound <= :income AND :income <= upper_bound OR lower_bound <= :income AND upper_bound = 'NULL'", {income: some_int})? I guess that could work, but feels... cumbersome.

Comment: You could switch to Postgres which has [a special value for `Infinity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html) as well as native [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html).  Or stick with your peasant DB and use `-1` as a hack ;)